# Is the book Linkers and Loaders by Levine still relevant?

Tags: compiler-construction, linker

I'm an applications programmer trying to learn systems programming and therefore I don't have a great understanding of these topics. *Linkers and Loaders* seems like a popular reference quoted in many online articles which talk about file formats, their linking and execution.

However the book was published back in 1999. Therefore, before purchasing and committing time to it, I want to know if the text is still relevant. That is, are the formats, protocols etc discussed in the book still in use? If not, what can one gain by reading it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having not read this book, and judging from a quick look at the table of contents I would say that it is still largely relevant. For example:

- Intel segmentation is still in use (in the 32bit world)
- ELF is still very common
- Linker control scripts (it would be nice if there was a full book on just this topic, most people never need to write a linker script, but when you need to write or modify one, it would be nice to have a good reference)
- Dynamic loading, and libraries are probably more common today then when the book was written.
- Relocation...
- Bootstrapping

Of course there are other things in there that are also still in common use, those are just a few biggies that caught my eye; but there are a few topics that I suspect most people will never care about again, such as:

- IBM360 file format.
- OMF files
- OSF/1 Pseudo static shared libraries

Frankly I am not sure people cared about those in 1999 either, but they are in there and maybe you can learn something from them none the less.

With that I would say this book is not a total waste of money if you want to learn general concepts of linking/loading, but if you are trying to solve a specific problem in this area then the web is probably all you need.